# Integrating function with /; in its definition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

why

```
f[x_ /; x>=0]:=x;
Integrate[f[x] ,{x,0,2 Pi}]
```

return unevaluated? Notice that the above definition of `f[x]` works OK with other Mathematica functions, such as `Plot`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the following works with `Integrate`

```
f[x_]:=x;
Integrate[f[x] ,{x,0,2 Pi}]
```

I am using version 11.3 on windows.

Comment: It's better to use ConditionalExpression, e.g., `Integrate[ConditionalExpression[x, x>0], {x, 0, 2Pi}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f[x_ /; x>=0]:=x` means "if `whatever>=0` rewrite `f[whatever]` as `whatever`. But that doesn't apply to `f[x]` when `x` is a symbol without a numerical value. Thus, `f[x]` simply remains `f[x]`. For abstracting the notion of a function with a break like this, use `Piecewise` or `HeavisideTheta`: `Integrate` understands what those mean.